# Convert word document to PDF document in SPO

Tags: community

Can we convert word document to pdf document in SharePoint online library using JSOM or CSOM?

If anyone has done this before, please provide some links.

Note: wanna make this as a community thread

Comment: Not possible yet via JSOM. You need to use either flow as mentioned here in [Convert SharePoint ffiles to pdf via flow](http://johnliu.net/blog/2017/10/convert-sharepoint-files-to-pdf-via-flow) and [here](https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2017/10/03/convert-sharepoint-documents-to-pdf-automatically-using-microsoft-flow/) or via a 3rd party conversion tool such as [Muhimbi](https://support.muhimbi.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002813708-About-the-PDF-Converter-Services-Online) which also has its own API

Answer (score 1):

This is available to onprem users using the word automation service:

https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2015/02/01/converting-a-librarys-word-documents-to-pdf-using-word-automation-services-for-sharepoint-2013/

At this time it is not available to online users without a third-party solution, but there is a uservoice open to request it:

https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/282887-sharepoint-hybrid-or-migration-to-office365/suggestions/17450962-word-automation-service-in-sharepoint-online

A similar question has already been asked that may provide some alternative solutions:

[How to automatically convert the word document into PDF?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60879/how-to-automatically-convert-the-word-document-into-pdf)