# what are possible ways to convert word document in sharepoint to pdf

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

i have office 365 account. is it possible to convert word document in sharepoint to pdf via add-in or any other way . i am looking to convert as following image by adding item like 'convert to pdf'.

[image]

[this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234828/convert-word-document-to-pdf-document-in-spo) thread says it is not possible without 3rd party api

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do it inside SharePoint Online without 3rd Party APIs.
[This API](https://www.convertapi.com/docx-to-pdf) will help you do it if you are willing to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this API in Microsoft Graph to do it.  It's specifically designed for this purpose:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/examples/document-conversion